# R featurePlot returning NULL

Tags: r, visualization, r-caret

I am trying to run various types of featureplot (part of the caret library) on my data for visualisation/ understanding of distribution. However when I try to run many of the commands, the result is NULL.

```
> featurePlot(x=feat, y=lab, plot="density")
NULL
```

Where feat is a matrix of my features (all numeric) and lab a binary column of labels (numeric). I have been able to use the "pairs" command with success but for some reason unable to use "ellispe" or "density". Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a sample dataset for reproducing your problem ?

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have to install the ellipse package.

```
> install.packages("ellipse")
```

Hope this will help.